# Round corners on only one Li element?

Tags: list, navigation, rounded-corners, rounding, nav

I am trying to create a single round (bottom right) corner on my navigation menu.
I have a ul id labeled "`main-nav`" and I created a li class labeled "`round`".
I added this li class to the Music link to get the round corners, but nothing happened.

**Here is a fiddle//**
http://jsfiddle.net/2qRLU/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `.round li` This will try to target list items nested inside elements with the "round" class.

You need to write `li.round` This targets list items that have the class "round" on them.

Note that spaces are important, it would be wrong to write `li .round` as this would target children of list items that have the "round" class.

http://jsfiddle.net/2qRLU/4/

---

If you wanted to style corners individually you can use the more specific versions:

```
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
```

I've styled them all here to show the different types, but in practice you probably just want to style one corner, so here's a version of your fiddle with only the bottom-right corner curved: http://jsfiddle.net/2qRLU/6/

---

Also, as a side note, unless you need to support older versions of the browsers, it is safe enough to just write border-radius without all the vendor prefixes. Browsers haven't needed vendor prefixes for border-radius for a while now.

You can test it without prefixes on your browsers here: http://jsfiddle.net/2qRLU/5/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :) I didn't know it had to be in a certain order to work. I have another quick question, what CSS can I add to style each corner?

Comment: @keihead Edited answer to show styling of corners individually.

Comment: That is the exact corner I wanted to be round :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: @keihead No problem! CSS3 sure makes pretty things effortless :)